# Solving geometry question by vector and pure geometry.

Tags: geometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry, triangles, geometric-transformation

> In $\Delta ABC$, $\angle A=\frac{\pi}{6}$, $H$ is the orthocentre and
> $D$ is the mid point of $BC$.
>
> Segment $HD$ is produced to $T$ such that $HD=DT$. Length $AT=\lambda
>  BC$. Find $\lambda$.

If possible, I am looking for method by pure geometry and vector both.

Let the circumcenter of $\Delta ABC$ be origin $(0)$

Position vector (P.V.) of $A,B,C$ be $a,b,c$ respectively.

$\implies$ P.V. of orthocentre $ H =\vec{a}+\vec{b}+\vec{c}$.

P.V. of $ D= \dfrac{\vec{b}+\vec{c}}{2}$.

Since $D$ is mid point of $H$ and $T$
$\implies \dfrac{\vec{b}+\vec{c}}{2}=\dfrac{(\vec{a}+\vec{b}+\vec{c})+\vec{t}}{2} \Longleftrightarrow \vec{t}=-\vec{a}$.

where $\vec{t}=$ P.V  of  $T$,  $\vec{AT}=-2\vec{a}$

Edit:
By the help from comment of user @Aretino, we see that $\vec{AO}$ and $\vec{OT}$ are parallel and same magnitude $\Longrightarrow$ length $AT$ is diameter of the circumcircle.

And by extended sine theorem, $BC =2R\sin(\pi/6)=R$.Hence $\lambda$ is 2.Now I am interested in pure geometrical proof?

Comment: How did you get P. V. of orthocentre?

Comment: @SarGe centroid divides circumcentre and orthocentre in ratio 1:2

Comment: $BTCH$ should be parallelogram, right?

Comment: If you denote the foot of the altitude from $B$ with, say, $E$, then $ABE$ is half of an equilateral triangle.

Comment: Number $\lambda$ should be given as a function of the sides of triangle $ABC$? Or else?

Comment: @Aretino edited.

Comment: Your vector proof is almost complete: just observe that $AT=2r$ is a diameter of the circumcircle, while by the chord theorem $BC=2r\sin30°=r$.

Comment: @Aretino ah yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\angle BOC = 2\angle BAC = 60$ so $BCO$ is equilateral, so $BC = OB = AO =R$.

- Since $T$ is reflection over a midpoint of a segment $BC$ we see that $T\in (ABC)$
- Reflection $H'$ over a segment $BC$ is also on $(ABC)$ and since $ED||H'T$ we see that $\angle TH'A = 90^{\circ}$ so $AT = 2R$

Conclusion $\lambda = 2$.

[image]

Comment: I am having trouble understanding why $T$ and $H'$ will lie on circle and how did you prove $\angle TH'A =\pi/2$?

Comment: $BTC = BHC =150 $  quadrilateral BTCH is paralelogram and $BH'C = BHC $ since $H'$ is reflection of $H$

Comment: sorry my geometry is poor. how did you get the angle BTC and why did H' lie on circumcircle?

Comment: Perhaps you should learn basic geometry by yourself then, it's not too hard :)

Comment: can you tell the specific topics to read for  understanding your answer?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HMx1ziQiU2s